# How to get the information of the exact file from S3 using ListVersionsRequest, JAVA?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have S3 bucket named `'groceries'` and with multiple files inside the folder `fruits`.
Files name would be like `('APPLE_1','APPLE_11','APPLE_1112','APPLE_3','APPLE_6')`

I basically want the `file_name` and it's version IDs for a given bucket and key. 
When I run the below code it also fetches other similar files like `(APPLE_11, APPLE_1112)`. 
What changes should I make in the below code to filter only `(APPLE_1)` ?

```
ListVersionsRequest request = new ListVersionsRequest();
request.withBucketName("groceries");
request.setPrefix("fruits/APPLE_1");
request.withMaxResults(20);
VersionListing versionListing = s3Client.listVersions(request);

int numVersions = 0, numPages = 0;
while (true) {
    numPages++;
    for (S3VersionSummary objectSummary:
        versionListing.getVersionSummaries()) {
        System.out.printf("Retrieved object %s, version %s\n",
            objectSummary.getKey(),
            objectSummary.getVersionId());
        numVersions++;
    }

    if (versionListing.isTruncated()) {
        versionListing = s3Client.listNextBatchOfVersions(versionListing);
    } else {
        break;
    }
```

```
current output
Retrieved object fruits/APPLE_1, version LFrP3YxiZu9S0
Retrieved object fruits/APPLE_11, version bHcs6Oh1leiPPvUB6NI07P0GB6
Retrieved object fruits/APPLE_1112, version Q9FD7fmVq_t1L3GPFitf
```

```
expected output
Retrieved object fruits/APPLE_1, version LFrP3YxiZu9S0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place an if condition inside the for loop. E. g.

```
for (S3VersionSummary objectSummary:
    versionListing.getVersionSummaries()) {
    if ( objectSummary.getKey().isEqual("fruits/APPLE_1"){// Or any other condition based on your requirement
        System.out.printf("Retrieved object %s, version    %s\n",
        objectSummary.getKey(),
        objectSummary.getVersionId());
    }
    numVersions++;
}
```